# Listeners retorna nulll laravel

Tags: laravel

Tengo un evento que se dispara bien, pero el listeners me retorna null en mi variable $event.

Me retorna null cuando lo llamo asi  `$event->email, $event->cantidad`

cuando hago un dd del `$event`

Me retorna lo anexado esto

```
App\Events\NewCobro {#1456 ▼
  +email: null
  +cantidad: null
  +socket: null
  +"help@prueba.com": "help@prueba.com"
  +"3": "3"
}
```

Donde los campos email y cantidad retornan null, pero mas abajo veo la informacion que necesito.

En donde me estoy equivocando .-.¡??

Este es mi Evento

```
<?php

class NewCobro
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $email;
    public $cantidad;


    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($email,  $cantidad)
    {


        $this->$email = $email;
        $this->$cantidad = $cantidad;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

este es mi listener

```
<?php



class CobrarMail
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  NewCobro  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(NewCobro $event)
    {
        dd($event);

       

        // Mail::to('admin@preuba.com')->queue(
        //     new Cobrar( $event->email, $event->cantidad)
        // );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu clase

```
class NewCobro
```

estas referenciando mal
así lo tienes:

```
$this->$email = $email;
$this->$cantidad = $cantidad;
```

así debería ser

```
$this->email = $email;
$this->cantidad = $cantidad;
```

sin el signo "$".

Comment: De ser así, en estos casos la pregunta se vota para terminar cerrada por errores tipográficos.